# How to disable pdf toolbar download button in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a web service which will return pdf stream for a given document id and I will set the content type to application/pdf and write the out put to IFRAME upto this point I am done and OK!
My problem is :
My  requirement is to disable the pdf download  toolbar button in IFRAME, is there any way using JavaScript or j query to disable the PDF toolbar buttons,
i tried some thing like this:

```
<iframe src="view/1.pdf?page=hsn#toolbar=0" width="875" height="95%" id="iframe11">
     <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
     </iframe>
```

I tried setting toolbar=0 for iframe tag but it dint work.
an anyone please tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: The toolbar you're referring to is most likely a built-in or external plugin used by the browser for displaying PDF files. You cannot disable it, as it's not part of the `iframe`.

Comment: You can't control that, since it's a browser feature. You should go for something like http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

Comment: hey did you solved your problem need help with that?

Answer (score 3):

I hope I am not very late to reply. But here's is something you can do to prevent the users. Use iFrame to display your PDF and make sure that you are displaying using Google. I used the following code :

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Here you can simply change the `url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf` and replace it by your own URL where you kept your PDF.

Comment: can we disable the right corner "Pop-out" option beside zoomin option ?

Comment: Hello @DrManishJoshi YES, by using the iFrame, you can get rid of the Right side options offered by the Browser.

Comment: how can we disable pop out option i am using iframe and getting pop out option?

Answer (score 3):

Use embed tag instead iframe tag:

```
<embed src="http://localhost/yourpdf.pdf#toolbar=0" style="width:600px; height:500px;">
```