# Disabling pdf toolbar in an iframe - php

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, pdf, iframe

I am displaying the contents of a pdf file into an `iframe`. This Works fine. However, I want to `hide the toolbar` (pdf save and download option).

I tried appending `#toolbar=0` in the `src` of the `iframe`. This works in `Chrome and Safari` but doesn't work in `Firefox and Internet Explorer`.

Could you please suggest any other way of displaying the contents of pdf without the save and download options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the toolbars surrounding an embedded pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104608/hiding-the-toolbars-surrounding-an-embedded-pdf)

Comment: @Gothdo: Thanks for your quick reply but it doesn't work in Firefox and IE.

Comment: See [How to disable pdf toolbar download button in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328820/how-to-disable-pdf-toolbar-download-button-in-iframe)

Comment: @Gothdo: Thanks a lot :-) . the above solution worked well with live (Internet) urls . However, I want it to work with local urls  (within an intranet).

Comment: You can use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) library.

Comment: Please give me the right solution.Above all tried but still not working in firefox.